# Error: Type FlatpickrModule does not have 'ngModuleDef' property

Tags: angular, typescript, flatpickr, ng-modules

Yesterday when I finished working on my app everything work correctly. Today I'm back and I have such error:

```
main.ts:12 Error: Type FlatpickrModule does not have 'ngModuleDef' property.
    at getNgModuleDef (core.js:3872)
    at verifySemanticsOfNgModuleDef (core.js:29039)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at verifySemanticsOfNgModuleDef (core.js:29046)
    at Function.get (core.js:29009)
    at getInjectorDef (core.js:325)
    at R3Injector.processInjectorType (core.js:18732)
    at core.js:18590
    at core.js:19036
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
(anonymous) @ main.ts:12
```

I can't see anything on my screen because of that. Please help I don't know what's wrong

Comment: What is FlatPickr? Where do you use it in your app?

Comment: I delete this FlatPickr from my program, but now I have the same problem with NguiDateTimePicker and I'm using it to create a calendar template to create reservation.